# decltype and static template method

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

In an attempt to use SFINAE, the following code fails to compile:

```
template<typename ObjectType, typename GroupA, typename GroupB, typename = void>
struct DelegateImpl; // default version

template<typename ObjectType, typename GroupA, typename GroupB>
struct DelegateImpl<ObjectType, GroupA, GroupB, decltype(GroupA::get<ObjectType>())>; // specialization
```

With GCC:

> error: template argument 4 is invalid

With MSVC, a surprisingly more helpful:

> error C3553: decltype expects an expression not a type

My aim is to have the compiler pick the specialization if the expression `GroupA::get<ObjectType>()` is valid.

**Question:** How do I use decltype with a static template method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither compilers give helpful errors actually. The real issue is you're missing the `template` keyword before `get`:

```
template get<ObjectType>()
```

See cppreference's page on [Dependent Names](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name)